# Error in giving reference to next node in SinglyLinkedList

Tags: java, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am working on Singly-linked list in which I have two classes `singlyLinkedList<E>` and `Node<E>`. When I create Object of `Node<E>` class it is giving me Error in passing arguments in `main()`.

Here is my Node class:

```
private static class Node<E>{
      private E element;
      private Node<E> next;
      public Node(E e,Node<E> n){
       element=e;
       next=n;
      }
      public E getElement(){
        return element;
      }
      public Node<E> getNext(){
        return next;
      }
      public void setNext(Node<E> n){      
       next=n;
      } 
   }
```

Error is in:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<Integer> node1= new Node<>(4,node2);
         Node<Integer> node2= new Node<>(4,node3);
         Node<Integer> node3= new Node<>(4,node4);
         Node<Integer> node4= new Node<>(4,null);
 }
```

It says:

1. `E` extends Object declared in class `SinglyLinkedList`
2. New instance ignored

Note:

It is not giving Error when I Pass its `next` to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your node declaration

```
Node<Integer> node4= new Node<>(4,null);
Node<Integer> node3= new Node<>(4,node4);
Node<Integer> node2= new Node<>(4,node3);
Node<Integer> node1= new Node<>(4,node2);
```